# Getting REQUEST_DENIED when calling Google's Autocomplete from a Browser

Tags: autocomplete

I have signed up for Google Places Autocomplete API and created a new key by going to following url.

http://code.google.com/apis/console/

I am using the generated key to do some testing on my browser. I am entering following url to search for City names starting with "San".

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=San&types=cities&sensor=false&key=

I keep getting "REQUEST_DENIED"  error message. Is there anything I am missing? I can see my usage counter going up every time I try to test this using a browser, but I keep getting REQUEST_DENIED message back. As per the google documentation it says this message is related to "Sensor" parameter. I tried setting this parameter to True/False but get the same results. Please help!

Thanks,